# Worked as a non-resident alien in the US (Canadian citizen and resident) for a few months under a TN visa, how do I file a tax refund?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, canada, non-resident, income-tax-refund

For a few months in 2014 I worked as a non-resident alien under a TN Visa in the U.S. I am a Canadian citizen and resident. I only worked a few months so I shouldn't have to pay much in taxes, but they withdrew taxes anyway. Now I need to file for a refund but I'm not even sure where to start. Resources, contacts to speak to, anything would be helpful.

I also need to report the income to the Canadian government; from what I've read, you're not supposed to be taxed twice, because of a US/Canada treaty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to file Federal taxes on form [1040-NR](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-1040NR,-U.S.-Nonresident-Alien-Income-Tax-Return) and State taxes on a similar State tax form (depending on the State you worked in). Since you were working on a TN visa, you should have gotten a SSN, so it should really be something straightforward.

You should claim the actual US taxes paid (those that remain paid after you get your refund - the amount on line 61 of the form 1040-NR) on your Canadian tax return.

Comment: I was only in the states for a few months (definitely under 183 days), and didn't make over 10k. Does that mean I am exempt under the tax treaty article XV? And then do I also have to fill out form 8833?

Comment: @shim consider if you even owe any taxes with such a low income, if there's no tax liability without invoking the treaty - why bother?

Comment: What / where are the rules for how much you need to make to owe taxes?